re-Generation has problem
Can you help me?
Generation has thrown an exception: list index out of range.
You can download my file.
It's very simple.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14evj9gA30U6AqdHvev4WrRp_mtcyshw5/view?usp=sharing

Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "this","issue with" or "question about". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See "What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

This rig type, in order to work, requires exactly a chain of 4 connected bones, plus the heel controller;
To solve, select the rig, go to edit mode, slect the foot and the thigh, press F to create a new bone, then parent all the chain with "Connected" option (Select Toe, Shift select Foot, press Ctrl P > Connected, if available; continue with the rest of the chain).
Then you can generate the rig.


Thank you very much!

Wow!
Incredable!

Thank you.
You are a genius
